# Jacobian of the solution from scipy.optimize is not equal to fjac of scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

When finding the root of the function using `scipy.optimize.root()` with argument `jac = True`, the `OptimizeResult.fjac` returns the values of Jacobian which are incorrect with the Jacobian of the solution.

For example,

```py
# objective function
def fun(x):
    return [x[0]  + 0.5 * (x[0] - x[1])**3 - 1.0, 0.5 * (x[1] - x[0])**3 + x[1]]

# function returns Jacobain at x
def jac(x):
    return np.array([[1 + 1.5 * (x[0] - x[1])**2, -1.5 * (x[0] - x[1])**2],
                [-1.5 * (x[1] - x[0])**2,
                1 + 1.5 * (x[1] - x[0])**2]])
from scipy import optimize
sol = optimize.root(fun, [0, 0], jac=jac)
```

After the solution is converged, `sol.fjac` is different from `jac(sol.x)`? I wouldn't able to understand what `fjac` denotes from `OptimizeResult`?

Any insights and corrections are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked using the debugger, and under the hood the default algorithm scipy.optimize.root uses is the _minpack.hybrj function. If you look at the documentation for fsolve (which also uses hybrj), it specifies:

> fjac
>   the orthogonal matrix, q, produced by the QR factorization of the final approximate Jacobian matrix, stored column wise

It thus seems like scipy's documentation is incomplete.

Source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html

Comment: I seem to be having a simialr problem. In my case, the jacobian is a single value. I think the QR decomposition of that would be unefined anyway right? But what I get from OptimizeResult seems to be the negative of the actual Jacobian. I can figure out why that would be.